# Find Selected Checkboxes in Repeater

Tags: asp.net

I have this code and need to know which checkboxes are selected in code behind

Can anyone help me ?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ParentRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ParentRepeater_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <label>
                    <%# Eval("TeacherName")%>
                </label>
                <br />
                <asp:Repeater ID="ChildRepeater" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="students" runat="server" /><%# Eval("StudentName")%>
                        </label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Loop through your `ParentRepeater` items
- Find the child repeater in each item, and loop through thats items
- Find the checkbox and check whether its checked
- If its checked, Response.Write ltlStudentName in same item

> ```
> For each item as repeateritem in ParentRepeater.Items
>     For each item2 as repeateritem in ctype(item.findcontrol("ChildRepeater"),repeater).items
>       if ctype(item2.findcontrol("students"),checkbox)
>          response.write(ctype("ltlStudentName"),literal).text)
>       end if
>     next
> Next
> ```

And change one line of your markup to:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="foods" runat="server" /><asp:literal id="ltlStudentName" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("StudentName")%>' />
```

Comment: sorry my friend i do this but the control is null

 foreach (RepeaterItem item in ParentRepeater.Items)
            {
                Repeater rep = ((Repeater)item.FindControl("ChildRepeater"));
                foreach (RepeaterItem item2 in rep.Items)
                {
                    
                    var ch = (HtmlInputCheckBox)(item2.FindControl("students"));
                    if (ch != null && ch.Checked == true)
                    {
                        Response.Write(ch.Value.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

Comment: @Developer Had you changed the checkbox ID? Updated answer

Comment: i do this :


foreach (RepeaterItem item in ParentRepeater.Items)
            {
                Repeater rep = ((Repeater)item.FindControl("ChildRepeater"));

                foreach (RepeaterItem item2 in rep.Items)
                {
                    var chkBox = item2.FindControl("students") as HtmlInputCheckBox;

                }
            }


but all checkboxs.Checked = false I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

this is the last try to solve and all checkbox.Checked not change all equal false

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in ParentRepeater.Items)
            {
                Repeater rep = ((Repeater)item.FindControl("ChildRepeater"));

                foreach (RepeaterItem item2 in rep.Items)
                {
                    var chkBox = item2.FindControl("students") as HtmlInputCheckBox;

                }
            }


<asp:Repeater ID="ParentRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ParentRepeater_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <label>
                    <%# Eval("TeacherName")%>
                </label>
                <br />
                <asp:Repeater ID="ChildRepeater" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <label>
                           <input type="checkbox" id="students" runat="server" /><asp:literal id="ltlStudentName" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("StudentName")%>' />
                        </label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```